# Error disabling welcome messages in Teams

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I have a Team with 10 channels and I need to disable sending emails in all case: when a new user is added...

I'm following this steps to disable the initial emails and when I finish the step 6 I'm obtaining a message with somethig like this: **"WARNING: The command completed successfully, but no configuration value has been changed from 'mygroup_objectid'"** .

```
$groupName = "<Replace Group Name>"
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
$UserCredential = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking
Set-UnifiedGroup $groupName -UnifiedGroupWelcomeMessageEnabled:$false
```

How can I solve this?

Regards

Comment: This means that your code worked but the settings were already set to what you wanted them to be. I have seen this message before even though changes were made. Have you checked the object to see if your changes have made a difference?

Comment: Hi @I.TDelinquent, first of all thanks for your reply. How can I check the object properties  in power shell?

Comment: I would presume there is a `Get-UnifiedGroup` command which should show you the current setting of `-UnifiedGroupWelcomeMessageEnabled`

Comment: Yes, with Get-unifiedGroup | Select-object -Property DisiplayName, WelcomeMessageEnabled I have obtained de value. Finally the comand to change the value works fine and the emails are disabled. Regards!

Answer (score 1):

If I check the property value with this command:

```
Get-unifiedGroup | Select-object -Property DisiplayName, WelcomeMessageEnabled
```

I can see that the previous steps worked fine